# Generate html from xsl without DOCTYPE

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to generate  html-output with xsl that has no doctype added to the output? 
If I don´t set any doctype myself it produces one on its own.

**EDIT :** 
Since I don´t think that this is possible, I solved my problem bysimply cutting away the DOCTYPE after the html is generated with followiing regex: '<&!DOCTYPE[^>]*>'

Comment: What have you tried, in the XSLT? What kind of DOCTYPE are you getting in the output? What output method are you using? Have you tried specifying `doctype-system=""` and `doctype-public=""` on `<xsl:output>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly tested with [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml), yes this is possible...I'm not sure what xslt library you're using so it could be a symptom of that.

If I use [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml) to run this transform against ANY xml file (which generates a minimum viable HTML5 document, minus DOCTYPE) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this output :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```